# H2 console throws away current work if the connection times out: is there no way to recover the entered queries?

Tags: console, h2

I had been composing a series of sql statements inside the H2 Console.  When I pressed execute, the page refreshed and I saw the initial logon screen, shown below.  **Using the browser history does not help:  the H2 Console page insists on returning to the state shown below**.

This is a serious usability issue - I will not always remember to do all of my work in a separate editor.  Has anyone come up with a workaround?

[image]

Comment: I've had this problem too, sometimes the command history works between sessions though. But I find using an external editor to be the best solution as it provides the useful features you can expect when writing code.

Comment: I had problems with lost data on other web sites, and now I use the Google Chrome Extension "Lazarus: Form Recovery". It "Autosaves everything you type so you can easily recover from form-killing timeouts, crashes and network errors.".

Comment: @ThomasMueller  Want points? make official answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lost form data is also a problem for other web pages (bug tracking for example).

For Google Chrome, there is an extension [Lazarus: Form Recovery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/lazarus-form-recovery/). It "Autosaves everything you type so you can easily recover from form-killing timeouts, crashes and network errors."